# NetSuite - Adding Features to Standard Transaction Form?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is is possible to add a script to a standard form in NetSuite?
My goal is to just display an inline text of a summation of a sublist column shown on the Bill of Materials Inquiry page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy Scripts to Record Types or to Custom Forms. You *cannot* deploy Scripts to the other native pages like Search Results, a Report, or a list of all the Sales Orders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you specify the customform field specifically, a script will run on every form.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if it's possible to deploy a script to a single specific non-custom form (adding a feature). These don't show up in the custom form lists.

Comment: Most standard records are negative values. For example, the internalid value of the Standard Inventory Detail Form form in one of my accounts is -10820.